# ¿Como crear un tabla desde el controlador con Laravel?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, controller

Hola estoy intentado crear un tabla en mi base de datos desde el controlador con los datos que recibo desde un formulario, estoy creando la tabla con el Schema::builder esto funciona pero no se me ocurre como agregar las columnas que me llegan del $request como un array lo que recibo del $request es lo siguiente:

Lo que recibo en el $request: `{"name":"vacunados","elements":["nombre","apellidos"]}`

Donde elements serian los campos de mi base de datos todos ellos seran de tipo String.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $tableName = $request->input('name');

            Schema::create($tableName, function($table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                //Aquí es donde no se como agregar las columnas
            });

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'tableName' => $tableName,
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Cualquier ayuda o consejo se los agradeceria mucho ire actualizando la pregunta con mis investigaciones e intentos y de nuevo muchas gracias.

He intendado de esta manera, pero sigo sin conseguir guardar los campos:

```
$tableName = $request->input('name');
$elements = $request['elements'];
  Schema::create($tableName, function($table)
  {
      $table->increments('id');
      // Columnas
      foreach ($elements as $element) {
          $table->string($element);
      }
      $table->timestamps();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola a todos después de horas al fin lo he logrado les comparto la solución:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $tableName = $request->input('name');
        
           
            if (!Schema::hasTable($tableName)) {
                Schema::create($tableName, function($table) use ($request)
                {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    foreach ($request['elements'] as $item) {
                        $table->string($item);
                    }
                    $table->timestamps();
                });    
            } else{
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'El catalago ya ha sido creado',
                ]);
            }
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Catalogo creado exitosamente',
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // DB::rollback();
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No es buena práctica tener en el controlador una creación de tabla, pero contestando a la pregunta.

```
Schema::create($tableName, function($table)
                {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string($request->elements[0]);
                    $table->string($request->elements[1]);
                });
```

Avanzando un poco encontre esta forma pero como respuesta obtengo que el $request es undefined
[image: Mi controlador]
[image: La respuesta del servidor]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, te lo agradezco el problema esta en que recibo N campos por eso estoy intentando recorrer en un foreach pero aun no lo logro, tu respuesta me serviria si supiera el número de campos que voy a recibir, gracias por tu respuesta igualmente, se aprecia.